# Is it possible to use the Xcode Simulator to test an application having only the .ipa file and no source code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Is it possible to run the Xcode Simulator, and test an application on different virtual devices, without having a source code but only the .ipa file, is it possible to test an application on Xcode with only attaching the .ipa file?

Did some research and found some answers, but couldn't find a resource that gives information on whether that's possible with only .ipa file.

Comment: Not sure if it will work, maybe drag the ```.ipa``` into the simulator and see if that installs it?

Answer (score 0):

.IPAs are built for real device architecture so it won't work with the simulator, to run on the simulator you must directly build your project via xcode.

Comment: That's not strictly true. It depends on where you got the ipa. If someone with the source code builds for the simulator and sends you that ipa then you can run it in the simulator. You send simulator builds to Facebook, for example, for them to test and approve when you want to access their api.  If you get the ipa from a device or the AppStore then you are right, it won't run on the simulator.